# error while run xcodebuild with xcpretty command in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, xcodebuild, xcrun

To run xcpretty command in xcodebuild, i use the below code:

```
import Foundation

class Command{

func command(args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.currentDirectoryPath = "/Users/Desktop/XCode/Test/"
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}


let xcodebuildCommand = Command()
xcodebuildCommand.command("xcodebuild","test","-project","proj.xcodeproj","-scheme","projScheme","-destination","platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air","  | /usr/local/bin/xcpretty --report html --output /Desktop/test_output/report.html")
```

the error is

```
xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action ' | /usr/local/bin/xcpretty --report html --output /Desktop/test_output/report.html'.
```

the below command run properly from terminal:

```
xcodebuild test -project proj.xcodeproj.xcodeproj -scheme projScheme -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air' | xcpretty --repor html --output /pathToReportfolder/report.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSTask` is not a shell, it will not interpret your shell script for you.

You'll need to manually set up an `NSPipe` to connect the standard output of your `xcodebuild` `NSTask` to an `xcpretty` `NSTask`.

```
import Foundation

func runCommand(workingDirectory: String? = nil,
                           stdin: NSPipe? = nil,
                          stdout: NSPipe? = nil,
                          stderr: NSPipe? = nil,
                            args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = NSTask()

    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args

    if let workingDirectory = workingDirectory {
        task.currentDirectoryPath = workingDirectory
    }

    if let stdin  = stdin  { task.standardInput  = stdin  }
    if let stdout = stdout { task.standardOutput = stdout }
    if let stderr = stderr { task.standardError  = stderr }

    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return (task.terminationStatus)
}

let pipe = NSPipe()

//omit "workingDirectory:" in Swift 2
runCommand(workingDirectory: "/Users/Desktop/XCode/Test/",
                     stdout: pipe,
                       args: "xcodebuild","test",
                       "-project","proj.xcodeproj",
                       "-scheme","projScheme",
                       "-destination","platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air")

//omit "workingDirectory:" in Swift 2
runCommand(workingDirectory: "/Users/Desktop/XCode/Test/",
                      stdin: pipe,
                       args: "/usr/local/bin/xcpretty",
                       "--report html",
                       "--output",
                       "/Desktop/test_output/report.html")
```

Comment: can u please give me link or an example how i can do this?

Comment: Yep, give me a second

Comment: There's a first (rought) go at it. I would avoid calling the function `command`, as that's a noun, not a verb. Functions are actions, not things, so their names should be verbs or verb phrases, like "runCommand". Also, I would put it in a struct, not a class.

Comment: Where? Compiles fine in swift 3

Comment: Oh, yeah, the behavior is different in Swift 2. The first keyword name is skipped in Swift 2, but required in Swift 3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115748/discussion-between-helper-and-amomchilov).

Comment: for swift 2.2,   remove workingDirectory keyword  when function is called.